# Platform-independent open source reference management software

Tags: open-source, reference-management

I looked at [Qiqqa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qiqqa) – which is good but not platform-independent.

Is there any platform-independent open source reference management software available which has the listed features of Qiqqa?

Good features of Qiqqa:

1. Free
2. [Comparison matrix](http://www.qiqqa.com/about/compare)

But only problem is [not platform-independent](http://www.qiqqa.com/Download?src=compare).

**Features required:**

1. Google-like search engine
2. Full text content search
3. Highlighting the entered search keyword
4. Previous/Next options as like in Folio Views
5. No. of hits before hitting to the actual search
6. Tree view or navigation pane to navigate through the results quickly
7. Caching frequent search for speed access

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Lzzy - added the features to the list.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! As it looked like you're after a web search engine, I've checked what Qiqqa really is and updated your post once more. You might wish to add what document formats you need supported. // And while waiting for good recommendations: Follow the Wikipedia link I inserted, scroll to the end of the page. There you can find some alternatives listed. [JabRef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JabRef) might be a candidate. Also see: [Comparison of reference management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software).